# Error in data.frame with differing number of rows in R,do I have an error in my syntax?

Tags: r, numbers, rows

```
 predicted.data <- data.frame(probability.of.Komplikace = logistic$fitted.values, parox_1 = ikemdata$parox_1)
```

> Error in data.frame(probability.of.Komplikace = logistic$fitted.values,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 4951, 4952

Comment: The error message is very clear.  The two vectors are different length.

Comment: sometimes you have NA values which the model removes, but you still have it in your original dataset. use this instead to see if it works: ikemdata[complete.cases(ikemdata),]$parox_1